# Network connection is not running in emulator,got this piece of error in DDMS,can anyone help me

Tags: android-emulator

Got following Trackback :

```
07-12 15:59:48.697: D/AndroidRuntime(2280): Shutting down VM
07-12 15:59:48.697: W/dalvikvm(2280): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
07-12 15:59:48.737: E/AndroidRuntime(2280): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-12 15:59:48.737: E/AndroidRuntime(2280): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.android.networkusage/com.example.networkusage.NetworkActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.networkusage.NetworkActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.example.android.networkusage-1.apk]
07-12 15:59:48.737: E/AndroidRuntime(2280):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1569)
07-12 15:59:48.737: E/AndroidRuntime(2280):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
07-12 15:59:48.737: E/AndroidRuntime(2280):     at android.app..ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
07-12 15:59:48.737: E/AndroidRuntime(2280):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
07-12 15:59:48.737: E/AndroidRuntime(2280):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-12 15:59:48.737: E/AndroidRuntime(2280):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-12 15:59:48.737: E/AndroidRuntime(2280):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
07-12 15:59:48.737: E/AndroidRuntime(2280):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-12 15:59:48.737: E/AndroidRuntime(2280):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
07-12 15:59:48.737: E/AndroidRuntime(2280):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
07-12 15:59:48.737: E/AndroidRuntime(2280):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
07-12 15:59:48.737: E/AndroidRuntime(2280):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-12 15:59:48.737: E/AndroidRuntime(2280): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.networkusage.NetworkActivity in loader dalvik..system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.example.android.networkusage-1.apk]
07-12 15:59:48.737: E/AndroidRuntime(2280):     at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:240)
07-12 15:59:48.737: E/AndroidRuntime(2280):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:551)
07-12 15:59:48.737: E/AndroidRuntime(2280):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader..java:511)
07-12 15:59:48.737: E/AndroidRuntime(2280):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
07-12 15:59:48.737: E/AndroidRuntime(2280):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1561)
07-12 15:59:48.737: E/AndroidRuntime(2280):     ... 11 more
07-12 15:59:50.997: I/Process(2280): Sending signal. PID: 2280 SIG: 9
```

Does anyone have idea what is wrong over here?

Answer (score 0):

The Exception is `Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.networkusage.NetworkActivity`

You will need to check your Android project for Java classes and package names. Most likely this is caused due to not defining the Activity class in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

Could you post your `AndroidManifest.xml`file?